# what is the efficient way to work with matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a matrix in numpy like:

```
In [66]: data = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)

In [67]: data
Out[67]: 
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5]])

In [68]: type(data)
Out[68]: numpy.ndarray
```

I want to get the product of data[0,:].T (which should a 3-by-1 matrix) and data[1,:] (which should be a 1-by-3 matrix), the result should be 3-by-3 matrix.

so, I wrote:

```
M = np.dot(data[0,:].T, data[1,:])
```

but this give me a number instead of a 3-by-3 matrix.

I've noticed that slicing in numpy.ndarray gives me a 1D array, thus data[0,:].T, data[1,:] are both 3-elements array, and dot product is just the summation of element-wise product.

```
In [92]: data[0,:].T.shape
Out[92]: (3L,)

In [93]: data[1,:].shape
Out[93]: (3L,)

In [94]: np.dot(data[0,:].T, data[1,:])
Out[94]: 14
```

Then, I find I could use numpy.matrix to transform data into matrix scenario, and then perform the slicing and dot product, this works.

However, I'm not quite sure about the efficiency of this transformation. As I need to handle large scale matrix, efficiency is my concern.

So, my question is, for my case, what is the best way to perform dot product on slicing?

Comment: The product of a 1x3 and a 3x1 is a 1x1, not a 3x3.

Comment: Also, `data[0,:]` isn't a matrix at all -- its shape is `(3,)`. To get what you're looking for (an outer product), you'll need to pass arrays with the shapes `(3, 1)` and `(1, 3)`.

Comment: and to nitpick a little more, you're using a 2d array. The matrix is a different datatype.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The product of a 1x3 and a 3x1 is a 1x1, not a 3x3.  However, both `data[0, :]` and `data[1, :]` are one-dimensional arrays, not two-dimensional matrices at all.  This because `data` is not, strictly speaking, a matrix, but a two-dimensional array.

If you want a 3x3, you would have to multiply the matrices in the other order (3x1 times 1x3).  You have a couple options for how to do that.  One is to use list indexing to get the row as a two-dimensional array (with one row):

```
>>> np.dot(data[[1],:].T, data[[0], :])
array([[ 0,  3,  6],
       [ 0,  4,  8],
       [ 0,  5, 10]])
```

Another possibility is to make `data` a numpy matrix (rather than an ndarray):

```
data = np.matrix(data)
```

Then you can do the operation somewhat more directly:

```
>>> data[1, :].T * data[0, :]
matrix([[ 0,  3,  6],
        [ 0,  4,  8],
        [ 0,  5, 10]])
```

(Note that you can use `*` for matrix multiplication if you use matrices.)

This is because numpy matrices return matrices, even when getting a slice that could be "squeezed" to a lower dimension; ndarrays do the squeezing, so grabbing a single row from a 2D array returns a 1D array, not a 1xN array.

Comment: @senderle: Oops, yeah.  I was going to mention that but forgot while I was writing the first part :-).

Comment: thanks, I should mean the dot product of 3*1 matrix and 1*3 matrix, I've re-edit my question.